# Is there a file that defines error messages?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, component, mysql

I would like to catch some exceptions to inspect the error code and determine if I should re-throw it with a more user friendly message. This would probably be most beneficial with MySQL errors. Is there a file of defined constants I could leverage for use in my component? Or, does everyone just hard-code the numeric value and/or create their own constants?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Exceptions to handle the error and your message.

If you are supporting both J2.5 and J3.x+ you can handle the error on a per-version case.

```
if (JError::$legacy) {
    // Use legacy error handling
} else {
    // Use PHP exception handling
}
```

here is [**an example**](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/0c8afc0f5d2b6f8091b938d3fb447946c2924625/administrator/components/com_admin/script.php#L94-L101) from the CMS of the kind of thing your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP has a built-in exception handler, then that's used.  Otherwise if a developer has created something to handle exceptions, that's used.

If you're unhappy with an existing exception handler, you can always extend it to make it more robust.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php

Comment: Thank you for the assistance but I wasn't asking about exception handling. I was asking about error codes. Is there a file(s) that can be included to define errors such as 1062 (duplicate entry). I prefer to use a constant such as ER_DUP_ENTRY in code as opposed to using the numeric value itself (it's more readable).

Answer (score 0):

in your template directory, there is a file error.php that you can modified to show more appropriate info on your errors.